# MongoDB - Robo3t: Failed to do query, no good nodes, Field 'cursor' must be a nested object

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

When viewing documents of a collection and trying to move between pages using "left" and "right" arrow buttons:

[image]

suddenly started to get the following error:

> Failed to load documents.
> Error:
> **Failed to do query, no good nodes** in MyCluster-shard-0, last error: can't query replica set node mycluster-shard-xx-xx.xxx.xxx.net:27017 :: caused by :: **Field 'cursor' must be a nested object** in: { conversationId: 7, done: false, payload: BinData(0, 723D424753514D4F432F494C776E73765A7263356774622F42564B695A62746F45523832456A5244475473346E30616B4B597938686352413D3D2C733D6F52614C316438586F...), ok: 1 }

Any idea of why is this happening?

Using Robo3T 1.4 on Ubuntu/Windows 10 - same thing on both OS.